# Smart Contract: false Transaction mined but execution failed (Merkle trees)

Tags: solidity, smart-contract, merkle

I'm trying to implement a smart contract whitelist using Merkle trees. I have been following along [This](https://dev.to/peterblockman/understand-merkle-tree-by-making-a-nft-minting-whitelist-1148) tutorial. However, instead of using the generate part, I used the online tool here: https://lab.miguelmota.com/merkletreejs/example/

In the tutorial, this is the code to allow the Merkle tree proof into my contract:

```
bytes32 public merkleRoot;

    constructor(bytes32 merkleRoot_) ERC721('Excited Ape Yacht Club', 'EAYC') {
        merkleRoot = merkleRoot_;
    }

    function mint(uint256 quantity, bytes32[] calldata merkleProof) public {
        bytes32 node = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, quantity));
        require(MerkleProof.verify(merkleProof, merkleRoot, node), 'invalid proof');

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            uint256 tokenId = _tokenIds.current();
            _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);

            _tokenIds.increment();
        }
    }
```

However when I try to mint, I get the following error in Remix:

> Fail with error 'invalid proof'

Using the online generator, I added in my 3 test addresses:

```
[
    "0xd27B22F898797e5b67748C4fEaAA267A0c4e692c",
    "0x696D3D057Fb1b3EE4f17ed5B8A771e5a0B6c0273",
    "0x73a5a5d09BD4CC7065Ef6D0E9B6544B82Ef1577d"
]
```

When I click compute, it gives me the following root:

```
0x40c352253148504193c8b7eaa9382f350fb285cc05b8e28b233cb06d6074f0d4
```

I then set this root like so:

```
 function setMerkleRoot(bytes32 _state) public onlyOwner {
        merkleRoot = _state;
    }
```

Now that is done and approves, I switch to "account 3". The online generator gives me the proof:

```
0xb9da26818c77fef205f0493b01019871f0972a9c0e6220951c168d6975ef1905
```

In the mint box, I add:

```
1, ["0x0bd01b10932d33b719364840269205a756359e0d4615c6ccde125d45db6984a2"]
```

Then it fails.

The decoded message for the input is

```
{
    "uint256 _mintAmount": "1",
    "bytes32[] merkleProof": [
        "0x0bd01b10932d33b719364840269205a756359e0d4615c6ccde125d45db6984a2"
    ]
}
```

When I use the verify section on that generator and enter in the details, It returns valid.

[image]

I'm at a loss as to what is wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the online generator you're using as *leaf* the address of the caller. In the solidity code you're using instead the hash of the address with the quantity of tokens to mint:

```
bytes32 node = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, quantity));
```

The solidity version is more correct, since you want to be sure the caller includes the correct number of tokens when calling the function. Otherwise users can use their personal merkle proof to mint how many tokens they want.

By the way, your code still allows the same person to continue minting using the same proof...

So, first you need to calculate the leaf for every user using the keccak256 formula, then use these leaves to calculate the merkle root and proofs.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution. Because I skipped the generation part and used the online generator I failed to see this. Lesson learned haha.

Comment: P.s I am already checking the max mint per address amount before the user can mint so I think that solves the other issue?

Comment: @JamesG yeah think so. Glad I could help!

Comment: As a thank you, would you like a spot on my free mint proj?

Comment: No thanks, I'm out of crypto for now